# docker-compose: how to map few ip to few containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have one host machine which have two ip addresses, also I have two nginx containers. How to map first ip to first nginx, and second ip to second nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that by *IP* you actually mean a socket, e.g. your `nginx1` container will listen to the IP address #1 (let's say `1.2.3.1`) on port 8080 and your `nginx2` container will listen to your IP address #2 (let's say `1.2.3.2`) on port 8081.

The option `--publish` will fulfill your need. It is used with `docker run` as so:

`docker run -d --publish=1.2.3.1:8080:80 -name nginx1 nginx`

This command will start the image `nginx` as a container named `nginx1` in background mode and the socket `1.2.3.1:8080` will be bound to the port `80` of the container. As for `nginx2`: `docker run -d --publish=1.2.3.2:8081:80 -name nginx2 nginx`.

---

To combine it with `docker compose` you'll just need to add these options in the `.yml` file and you're done!